# Use JSON PUT inside C program

Tags: c, json

I've gotten a hold of a few JSON libraries but have yet to install any of them since I may or may not need it for my purpose.

I am trying to create a console application that simply sends PUT requests to a server and then get the response from the server of that PUT request.

When using the Advanced REST Client extension within Google Chrome, I can send PUT requests and get a response back.  Based on my response, I can go ahead and send another request to do something else that I desire, such as update a field of a specific object on the server side.

I want my application to be able to behave like a REST client but really it only needs to do 1 thing, PUT.  It does not need to do GET, POST, etc.

I have a very bare template made right now with just a simple menu and some error checking.

What do I need to do to get the ball rolling?

EDIT: One other detail, I will be doing this on Windows (sadly enough) and probably using a free IDE such as CodeBlocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) Grab some of the examples (there is one for [put](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/httpput.html))  and have a go, 4 lines of code needed for a simple http client, see that in operation and then change the payload to contain your PUT request.

Comment: In their example, they are using a file.  For my use, I am generally used to having a header, which always stays the same, and a payload, which I generate manually.

Comment: so, instead of reading the file into memory, you already have the data in memory. The example isn't there to show you to to read the data to send, its showing you how to send it.

Comment: So for instance, instead of sending a file as the data, I could send formatted JSON fields (my payload) to the server?

Comment: of course, the readfunction callback already says "in real world situations you'd do it differently" - return your own data in the stream parameter, or look at the other curl options for something more synchronous.